# PHP - simplyfy the code - something like MVC part

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, properties, overloading

Im .NET programmer, but totally new in PHP. Im fighting with this for hours.

I need to simplyfy data transfer from interface to database. I have something like this:

```
    $default = new stdClass();

            // default values - all of them should be set to default value
            // some of them will be overwritten later, but only one of them


    $default->{'val-string'} = ''; // default values start
    $default->{'val-int'} = 0;
    $default->{'val-float'} = 0;
    $default->{'val-image'} = ' ';
    $default->{'val-datetime'} = 0;
    $default->{'val-boolean'} = false; // default values end


    $container = array(); 


    $row = clone $default;
    $row->{'field_id'} = 1;
    $row->{'field_name'} = $nameoffield1;
    $row->{'val-string'} = 'Diffrent types are filled for diffrent rows';
    $container[] = $row;

    $row = clone $default;
    $row->{'field_id'} = 2;
    $row->{'field_name'} = $nameoffield2;
    $row->{'val-int'} = $valueoffield2;
    $container[] = $row;

    $row = clone $default;
    $row->{'field_id'} = 3;
    $row->{'field_name'} = $nameoffield3;
    $row->{'val-datetime'} = current_time();
    $container[] = $row;

    // there
    // is
    // a lot
    // of these 
            //rows

$result = $database->insertContainer($db_session, $container);
```

At the end need something like that "pseudocode .NET mixed with php"

```
list_of_rows.AddItem(makeRow($field_id1, $name1, (int)$dataforint)));
list_of_rows.AddItem(makeRow($field_id2, $name2, (string)$dataforstring));
list_of_rows.AddItem(makeRow($field_id3, $name3, (date)$datafordate));
list_of_rows.AddItem(makeRow($field_id4, $name4, (boolean)$dataforboolean));

$result = $database->insertContainer($db_session, list_of_rows);
```

If overloading like this is not possible (or very complicated) in PHP - i will be happy if someone give me any better solution than mine code at the top.

Comment: for the mvc, did you look for any specific frameworks such as cakephp?

Comment: you can try to using func_get_args inside a method and then do type checks or you can use also the __call magic function.

Comment: What's that database interface you're using? Have you looked into any of the existing PHP DALs or ORMs? Trying to just do it the same way you're doing it in .NET won't translate well. The question is, what do you want to accomplish and what's the best way to do that in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a possible approach. You can also use the __call method to achieve this. This is just a quick example. Either this, or you might use an ORM like propel to achieve something similair. It really depends on what the task is.

```
class Row_Builder {

    protected $default = array();

    public function __construct() {
    $this->default['field_id'] = null;
    $this->default['field_name'] = null;
    $this->default['val-string'] = null;
    $this->default['val-int'] = null;
    $this->default['val-float'] = null;
    $this->default['val-image'] = null;
    $this->default['val-datetime'] = null;
    $this->default['val-boolean'] = false;
    return;
  }  

  public function setValues() {
    // we only need the fist argument in this case.
    $params= func_get_arg(0);
    if(isset($params)) {
      foreach($params as $key => $value)  {
        if(array_key_exists($key,$this->default)) {
          $this->default[$key] = $value;
        }

      }
    }

  }

  public function __get($key) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $this->default)) {
      return $this->default[$key];
    } 
  }
}

$row = new Row_Builder;
$row->setValues(array('field_id' => 1, 'field_name' => 'some value', 'val-string' => 'here is a str value'));

print $row->field_name;
```

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what i need. Thank you.

If i understand this - i can set only values i need, like this:

     $row->setValues(array('field_id' => 1, 'field_name' => 'Name'));

All fields in array will be available, and two of them will store values i set. Other fields will be filled with default data. Right?

Comment: @Kamil the default values are set when the object is initiated exactly. See the example inside __construct function.